Is there any open/legal collection of open profile Instagram reels, stories or similar short videos to train our models on?
I am developing a model for which I need a collection (100k+ at least) of reels and stories of the kind that are posted to Instagram. While there are scrapers and bots I was wondering if there is an existing collection (like million songs database for music).
Thanks!
Since public profile content is open to access, I found people suggesting accessing these content, but I'm not sure if this is a good idea and also it sounds very slow to access them individually.
